# Can this warning be avoided in apache airflow 2.0?

Tags: airflow

I am using **airflow v2.0** on windows 10 WSL (Ubuntu 20.04).
The warning message is :

```
/home/jainri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py:1342: PendingDeprecationWarning: The requested task could not be added to the DAG because a task with task_id create_tag_template_field_result is already in the DAG. Starting in Airflow 2.0, trying to overwrite a task will raise an exception.
  warnings.warn(
Done.
```

> `Due to this warning, the dags showing in web UI are also some example dags included with apache airflow. I have setup **AIRFLOW_HOME** and it also picks up dags from there. But the list of example dags also displayed. I have posted the image of WEB UI also.`

[WebUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jATR9.png)

This is the dag below that I am trying to run:

```py
import datetime
import logging

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

#
# TODO: Define a function for the python operator to call
#

def greet():
    logging.info("Hello Rishabh!!")

dag = DAG(
    'lesson1.demo1',
    start_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    end_date 
)

#
# TODO: Define the task below using PythonOperator
#

greet_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='greet_task',
    python_callable=greet,
    dag=dag
)
```

Also, the main issue is like the list of dags showing in webUI is some example dags. That shows up a huge list along with my own dags. Which makes it cumbersome to look for my own dags.

Comment: Please don't post text as image. Edit your question and make it indexable

Comment: I have edited my question as per your suggestion. Thanks Olaf.

Comment: Please post your actual DAG

Comment: @kaxil I have posted my dag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, the error you are seeing is because of `airflow/example_dags/example_complex.py` (one of the example_dags) that is shipped with Airflow.

Disable loading of example_dags by setting `AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES=False` as an environment variable or set `[core] load_examples = False` in `airflow.cfg` ([docs](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configurations-ref.html#load-examples)).

Comment: Just a note, this will be fixed in Airflow 2.0 release. Currently, the only alpha version is out for testing and should not be used in Production.

Comment: After editing airflow.cfg according to your answer, I used `airflow initdb` to reset the list of dags loaded into the Airflow web UI and it worked.